# @Secured annotations not working in AspectJ Mode with Autoproxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, aspectj

I'm trying to get my Spring MVC app to play nice with Spring @Secured annotations and AspectJ auto-proxying but it doesn't seem to be proxying or recognising my @Secured annotations. I have a controller like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApplicationController {

    private ApplicationFactory applicationFactory;

    @Inject
    public ApplicationController(ApplicationFactory applicationFactory) {
        super();
        this.applicationFactory = applicationFactory;
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_USER")
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public Application getApplicationInfo() {
        return applicationFactory.buildApplication(this);
    }

}
```

And a spring security XML that looks something like this:

Code:

```
  <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" mode="aspectj" proxy-target-class="true" />

  <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:http-basic/>
  </security:http>
```

The above is being loaded by a no-xml Spring @Configuration component like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource("classpath:security.xml")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

Which in turn is loaded using a Servlet 3.0 WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        context.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        servletContext.addListener(new Log4jConfigListener());

        final DelegatingFilterProxy proxy = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain", context);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = servletContext.addFilter("securityFilter", proxy);
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(REQUEST), false, "/*");

        final DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", servlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }

}
```

However, Spring Security isn't detecting the annotation and I'm still able the secured endpoint above without being authorised. According to the [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context), this maybe because the `<global-method-security>` element is being loaded in the wrong application context, but I don't know how to ensure this using the above no-xml Spring configuration.

Am I missing something? I tried adding the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) to my application configuration but that didn't help either. Is there anyway to have run time weaving or will I have to use compile time weaving to enable annotation-based security for my application?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why do you need `mode = "aspectj"`?

Comment: I'm trying to use @Secured annotations with auto proxying without the need for load/compile time weaving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using AOP with Spring you can choose between two implementations of AOP:

- Spring AOP implementation doesn't require weaving, but it's only applicable to beans managed by Spring and have [some limitations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)
- AspectJ AOP implementation can work for all objects and doesn't have limitations of Spring AOP, but requires compile-time or load-time weaving

`mode="aspectj"` tells Spring to use AspectJ for AOP implementation, therefore security aspect won't work without weaving in your case.

The term "AspectJ auto-proxying" has nothing to do with using AspectJ as AOP implementation - it's a feature that allows you to use AspectJ API (rather than implementation) with Spring AOP.

So, in your case you can use Spring AOP implementation, because controller is a Spring bean, therefore you should remove `mode="aspectj"`. Also note that your controller should have no-arguments constructor - it's one of the limitations of Spring AOP.

Comment: You're right, fixed now. Its a shame Spring AOP CGLIB auto-proxying doesn't support constructor injection.

Comment: @RicardoGladwell: It does, you just need to create no-args constructor in addition to you `@Inject` constructor.

Comment: does it have to be a public constructor?

Comment: No (unless you run in environment where `setAccessible()` is disallowed).

Answer (score 4):

To expand a bit on @axtavt's answer, the `mode="aspectj"` option in `global-method-security` specifically requires that your code has been woven with the [`AnnotationSecurityAspect`](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/aspects/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/intercept/aspectj/aspect/AnnotationSecurityAspect.aj) from the `spring-security-aspects` module.

There's some [sample code](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/samples/aspectj/src) which demonstrates it in use. It just consists of a secured bean and some Junit test, but the code is compiled with the AspectJ compiler. The [application context](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/samples/aspectj/src/main/resources/aspectj-context.xml) also shows how simple it is compared with what was required before namespace support was added (the commented out beans).